# JavaScript & JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am new to JS & JSON.I am struggle with converting JSON array to JavaScript array.How to do that? Here is my code:

```
var data = {
items: [
<? $i=1; foreach($query->result() as $row){ ?>
<? if($i!=1){ ?>,<? } ?>
{label: '<?=$row->district_name;?>', data: <?=$row->countid;?>}
<? $i++; } ?>
]
};
```

how to get the JSON array value to JavaScript Array.
i just tried but it doesn't work. please some suggestions.
here is my javascript array

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
chartData[i]=data.items[i].label+";"+data.items[i].data;

}
```

Comment: Obligatory read: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). And another thing: do you know what that first piece of code does? Don't tell me you don't have to think about it. That's why one shouldn't mix PHP and client-side code this way.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say more about how it "doesn't work."

Comment: Don't forget to ask as well how to convert a PHP array to JSON.

Comment: Also, you may learn something by doing a "view source" on the resulting page.  I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you posted, but you didn't post any context for where "data" is declared, nor where that "for" loop is.

Comment: That PHP isn't generating JSON. The resulting code has errors in it (using `'` to delimit values is an obvious one). [PHP has functions for handling JSON](http://php.net/json) — use them!

Comment: @Quentin that's true, it's not JSON, but in the apparent context of what's been posted it doesn't have to be strict JSON.

Comment: it shows all values of data array when i print . say how to copy to javascript plain aray

Answer (score 1):

As the others already said, be careful when talking about JavaScript and JSON. You actually want to create a JavaScript object and not JSON.

Don't mix PHP and JavaScript like this. It is horrible to maintain. Create an array beforehand, encode it as JSON<sup>*</sup> and print it:

```
<?php

    $results = $query->result(); // get results

    function m($v) { // a helper function for `array_map`
        return array('label' => $v->district_name, 
                     'data' => $v->countid);
    }

    $data = array('items' => array_map('m', $results));

?>

var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

---

*: Here we use the fact that a JSON string is valid JavaScript too. You can just `echo` it directly in the JavaScript source code. When the JS code runs, it is not JSON, it is interpreted as JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

You really oughtn't think too hard about this. PHP does a fine job of serializing arrays as JSON.

```
var data = {
  items: <?php
    $arr = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
      $arr[] = array('label' => $row->district_name,
                     'data'  => $row->countid);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>
};
```

*[insert same disclaimer as above about how you're really trying to create a JavaScript object]*

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON:

```
var foo = "{bar: 1}";
```

This is not JSON:

```
var foo = {bar: 1};
```

Your code snippet is not using JSON at all and my educated guess is that you don't even need it. If you are using PHP to generate some JavaScript code, you can simply tweak your PHP code to print text that will contain *real* JavaScript variables. There is no need to encode stuff as plain text!

Now it's clear we don't need JSON, let's use a dirty trick. PHP has [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) and we can abuse the fact that a JSON strings resemble JavaScript variables. All we have to do is call json_encode() on our PHP variable and *forget* to quote the result:

```
<?php

$foo = array(
    'bar' => 1,
    'dot' => FALSE,
);

echo 'var JSONString = "' . json_encode($foo) . '";' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'var realVariable = ' . json_encode($foo) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
```

Compare:

```
var JSONString = "{"bar":1,"dot":false}";
var realVariable = {"bar":1,"dot":false};
```

**Edit:** Yep, my JSONString is not a valid string... but we get the idea <:-)